# Sending Hex through UART

Tags: c, hex, avr, uart

I am trying to send a hexadecimal data over UART to my AVR. The problem is, I can't send more than two pair of hex. I need to send more than two, like 9-10.

For example:

I could only send `0x2f` and `0x3f`.
If I send more than that, its always minus.

I need to send `0xff234f3a3f`.

My code:

```
sendString("wish me luck\n");

while(1)
{               
    char str[35];
    int i;

    printf("enter the code :\n");
    scanf("%x", &i);
    printf("%#x (%d)\n",i,i);
}
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: sorry, i was posting the wrong one.but even with this code, it still only able to send two pair of hex. nothing more, what to do?

Comment: Curious. First code used a `char` array of 30, now code uses `int`.  Why use type `int` with `"%x"`?  What does your documentation say about what type should be used with `"%x"`?

Comment: nah.. its just a leftover from previous code, but the main focus here is to send more than 2 pair of hexdata. and the %x is the only data type i found in internet that could do what i want

Comment: the int i; declarations only serve 16bit (2 byte) of memory. 10 hex need 10x8 bits of memory. the longest data type in AVR is only 64 bits (uint64_t)

Comment: You want to send **to your AVR** from what? Were does your code run? Or you want to send **from your AVR**? It is really not clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by storing the data you wish to send in a software buffer and as soon as avr sends the 1byte of uart data fill the uart register with the byte from Software buffer. You can do something like this:-

```
char ar[] = "hello";
for (i = 0; i < strlen(ar); i++) {
    while ((UCSR0A & (1<<UDRE0)) == 0);
    UDR0 = ar[i]; 
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: the int i; declarations only serve 16bit (2 byte) of memory.

Comment: 16 bit is good enough it allows you to store 65536 elements in char array

Answer (score 0):

AVR UART has a size limitation as it is in embedded environment so the UART buffer is only 8/16 bits . You are able to send 2 bytes of data , to send more you need to make a loop to send the remaining data bytes.

Comment: how could i do that? a lil example will do it for me. thx in advance.

Comment: Look at below link http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/168709/how-to-send-string-in-serial-communication-in-avr-c  might help.